# Как обратиться к API VK через node-vk-bot-api

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api

Есть библиотека - [node-vk-bot-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-vk-bot-api)
Как с помощью нее обратиться например за методом users.get (возвращающее информацию о профиле)

До этого использовал библиотеку [botact](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botact)
Там в документации был пример 
**Usage:**

```
const data = await bot.api('users.get', {
  user_ids: 1
})
```

С этим всё понятно. Но вторая библиотека старая и не реагирует на сообщения в беседе, только в ЛС.

Answer (score 3):

node-vk-bot-api предоставляет возможность работы с API при помощи метода "execute"

**Пример**

```
bot.execute("users.get", { user_ids: 1456214 }, (result) => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: Дай бох тебе здоровья!